# How to configure NDK with Kotlin in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, kotlin

I'm newbie with kotlin, I have successfully configured NDK with Android Studio (without kotlin) ie in java.

but now google has introduced kotlin so I want to change my existing project to kotlin with NDK support.

this is my java code

```
 static
 {
     System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
 }
 public native String stringFromJNI(int i);
```

Please help me how to do same code in kotlin

Comment: Did you try setting up Kotlin in addition to the NDK? Did you encounter any problems while doing so?

Comment: Have you read: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/faq.html

Comment: @zsmb13 Yes I have setup with out any errors

Comment: So what is the queston?

Comment: plesae see my edited question

Answer (score 2):

You can read this post on Medium: [Android NDK: Interaction of Kotlin and C/C++](https://proandroiddev.com/android-ndk-interaction-of-kotlin-and-c-c-5e19e35bac74)

In this article, authors saw how to make Kotlin communicate with C/C++.

**For Example:**

Kotlin code:

```
class Store {

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("Store")
        }
    }

    @Throws(IllegalArgumentException::class)
    external fun getString(pKey: String): String
}
```

C++ code:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_ihorkucherenko_storage_Store_setString(
        JNIEnv* pEnv,
        jobject pThis,
        jstring pKey,
        jstring pString) {
    StoreEntry* entry = allocateEntry(pEnv, &gStore, pKey);
    if (entry != NULL) {
        entry->mType = StoreType_String;
        jsize stringLength = pEnv->GetStringUTFLength(pString);
        entry->mValue.mString = new char[stringLength + 1];
        pEnv->GetStringUTFRegion(pString, 0, stringLength, entry->mValue.mString);
        entry->mValue.mString[stringLength] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Samples here: https://github.com/KucherenkoIhor/KotlinWithAndroidNdk